# React.createElement: type is invalid but TypeScript compiles correctly. Why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a small project created using the [TS react guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html), using the following webpack config:

```
module.exports={entry:"./src/index.tsx",output:{filename:"bundle.js",path:__dirname+"/dist"},devtool:"source-map",resolve:{extensions:[".ts",".tsx",".js",".json"]},module:{rules:[{test:/\.tsx?$/,loader:"awesome-typescript-loader"},{enforce:"pre",test:/\.js$/,loader:"source-map-loader"},{test:/\.css$/,loader:"css-loader"}]},externals:{react:"React","react-dom":"ReactDOM"},mode:"development"};
```

And the following tsconfig.json:

```
{compilerOptions:{outDir:"./dist/",sourceMap:!0,noImplicitAny:!0,module:"commonjs",target:"es6",jsx:"react",resolveJsonModule:!0,experimentalDecorators:!0,emitDecoratorMetadata:!0,types:["reflect-metadata"]},include:["./src/**/*","./definitions.d.ts"]};
```

I want to include the official google react material components but even after defining the [Select component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/tree/master/packages/select) (As the MCR project does not provide typings) like this in the definitions.d.ts file:

```
declare module '@material/react-select' {
  export interface SelectOption {
    label: string,
    value: string,
    disabled: boolean
  }

  export interface SelectProps {
    label?: string;
    onChange?: (event: SelectEvent) => void;
    options?: [SelectOption];
  }

  export interface SelectEvent {
    target: SelectOption
  }

  export class Select extends React.Component<SelectProps> {

  }
}
```

The project does compile with webpack just fine, however when i try to display that Select component i get this error:

[image: React errors]

For reference, this code is representative of that which is triggering this error (where options is generated from a map call of the JSON data i want to show to `<option key={x.id} value={x.id}>{x.name}</option>` elements):

```
import { Select, SelectEvent } from "@material/react-select"
...

onReferenceOptionChanged(event: SelectEvent): void {
  ...
}

render() {
  if (this.state.showProgress) {
    return (<Loader showLoading={true} progressMessage="Loading forms..."></Loader>);
  }

  if (this.state.showErrorMessage) {
    return (<Loader showErrorMessage={true} retryCallback={this.handleRetry}></Loader>);
  }

  var refOptions = this.state.references.map(x => {
    return <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>{x.name}</option>
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Select onChange={(event) => this.onReferenceOptionChanged(event)}>
        {refOptions}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can i modify my configuration so this does not happen?

EDIT:
I get these warnings from webpack compilation, maybe they are related:
[image: Webpack Warnings]

This is my package.json deps block:

[image: package.json]

Merely changing `Select` to `select` fixes the issue by restoring the stock Chrome select element.

Comment: You should share the code where you used this component. I think it nothing to do with your configuration. The error message is not a TypeScript message as TypeScript is only for compiler time type check.

Comment: I do believe either Typescript or Webpack are somehow missing the MDR Select classes from the emitted bundle, as Typescript should be ensuring that the corresponding JavaScript is indeed imported from the module. I'm not too savvy on this, just starting.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Are you sure you get the error message to the Select component?

Comment: @Peter Added more info to the question

Comment: I understand your problem better now, but with some of the configuration I'm out of my depth. I still think, that it is not your definition file, because that is just for compile time check. I suspect the problem is with Loader. Try to eliminate it from your render method for a test.

Comment: Replacing the Loader elements (my own components, written in typescript) with empty <div> tags made nothing. The error comes from the Select element. Maybe writing the definition manually made it an ambient module that TypeScript is not bundling into the final JS file? I recall declaring a module like this could have a similar side-effect